# Watcher not working with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am having an issue with watchers not being triggered upon data change in my component. The property in the data is reactive, as it has been set upon component creation and not later on.

Here is the piece of code, in which the issue is:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nlpvz0y6m

To explain in more detail, the status property gets its status from the parent, which intern gets it from a Vuex state object, it is being passed to the component successfully, as I am able to log it and change it.

However, when I setup a watcher, to execute a function upon a change in it's value, it simply doesn't trigger. Regardless how I make the change - whether with an internal method of the component or an event.

What I need is for the watcher to trigger upon change of the status property, but am not certain why it does not reflect it at all.

The structure is as it follows: BottomBar is the parent, a bool value is passed as property to Spin.vue as a prop and then the prop is assigned to a data property on the child component.

The bool value itself, comes from index.js, where the Vuex instance is.

Answer (score 4):

In the console, it is showing the following two errors

```
[vuex] unknown getter: isSpinning
[vuex] unknown mutation type: spinIt
```

The issue seems to be how the store is set up. Try this.

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    controls: {
      spin: false
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isSpinning: state => {
      return state.controls.spin;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    spinIt(state) {
      return (state.controls.spin = !state.controls.spin);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had your mutations and getters sat inside your state. I have moved them outside, and updated the references inside to make the code work as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xyxmvr8jj